# Google Contacts API version 3.0 (.NET) - OAuth2.0 CRUD Operations

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-oauth, google-contacts-api

I have setup up a .NET console application that will do the following:

- Access the Google Contacts API for my personal Google Account
- Perform basic CRUD (create, read, update, delete) operations to these contacts

I believe executing the CRUD operations will be straight forward using the following documentation:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#about_authorization_protocols

**However, my problems are occurring when trying to authenticate my connection using OAuth2.0.**

I am using the Google.GData.Contacts .NET NUGET Package using the code from the following example:

https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/oauth2_sample/oauth2demo.cs?r=1159

```
OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters() {
    ClientId = clientId,
    ClientSecret = clientSecret,
    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
    Scope = scopes
};

string url = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters);
Console.WriteLine("Authorize URI: " + url);
parameters.AccessCode = Console.ReadLine();

OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);
```

As this code was last updated in 2012, I'm worried it might no longer be relevant for my task.

**Major Questions:**

- I'm not sure exactly what the parameters.AccessCode value is.  Where does this value come from?
- Based upon my use case am I using the correct OAuth2.0 approach?  You can can setup authentication for a Service Account, Web Application, or Native Application.  The above code implies Native Application
- Is there a better way to handle my task?

Answer (score 0):

The `access code` should be used only for [WebServer Applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2?csw=1#webserver).

I'm not sure if your console app will run in an environment where a browser can be launched or not.

If yes (your app is running in a environment where a URL can be launched), use the documentation for [Installed Applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp).

If browser is not present, you can use the documentation for [Applications on limited-input devices](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2?csw=1#device).

If the library you're targeting to use (NUGET, whatever) has no support for this flow, don't worry: it's easy to write custom code. You can use any library able to do HTTP/HTTPS requests, like  or [Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx) (Windows 8 and later).

Additionally, you can use contact import services like [CloudSponge](http://www.cloudsponge.com/contact-importers/gmail), which offers a [.Net API](http://www.cloudsponge.com/integrations/net) and support for other contact sources (in case you want expand your address book support in the future).

Answer (score 0):

AccessCode comes from the URL created in that Line above. See here:

```
string url = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters);
```

url contains a URL now for your browser. Fill it in Chrome/Firefox/etc and confirm the google request to get the AccessCode. It will look like this "4/bAQT1qf66vpkmfU8xDkoVZmedvVoYDH6KovzcHcA5pc" but will change every time you call the URL.

```
Console.WriteLine("Authorize URI: " + url);
```

now you can see the url but you might not be able to copy it from your console. But if you get it into your browser, it will result in a google dialog to get your AccessCode.